# (MATLAB) On drawing elements randomly from vectors and rows randomly from matrices without replacement in for loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, random, vector

So, two related questions for code I'm writing for an experiment I'm building in MATLAB. Firstly, I have a 20 row column vector, called `block1` (with a number in each of the 20 slots).

I want to draw a number randomly from the vector without replacement and repeat this until there are no numbers left in the vector (so 20 times total). I have the following line within a for loop (which is set to run for 20 iterations), which draws the random number from the vector and sets it equal to variable rand_num:

```
rand_num = randsample(block1,1,false)
```

It draws the random number just fine, but the problem is that the draw without replacement part doesn't work. Initially I thought this was because the vector was reset at the beginning of each iteration of the for loop. To make sure, I debugged and found that even when I stop the for loop before the first iteration finishes (and after the random number has been drawn), there are still 20 numbers in the vector (when there should be 19). Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

The second question is as follows. For the same experiment, I have a 20 by 6 matrix called `pick_matrix`. During each iteration of the same for loop as above, I want to pick one row at random from the matrix (including every element in that row; so 6 elements total for each row) without replacement and assign that row to variable `random_row`.

I figured out the code to pick a row at random and assign it to random_row, but I'm having the same problem as with the last question: the without replacement part isn't working.

Comment: There's no way this can be answered if you don't provide code. Generally I don't think you need `for` loops for this (you seldomly do in Matlab). Have a look at `randperm`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randsample` works fine, and exactly as expected. You just need to call it once before your loop rather than twenty times within the loop. Read the help carefully - `randsample` does not change anything about the input variable `block1`. Generally speaking (ignoring globals and such), input variables are *not* changed by Matlab functions, even if they are changed within a function, unless they are then explicitly output.

e.g. consider this:

```
function y = myfunc(x);

    x = x*2;
    y = x*3;
    disp(x)

end
```

Within the function, `x` is doubled. Say I have a variable `x` in my workspace, value 10. If I call `y = myfunc(2)`, I will see "4" displaced - and `y` will be output as 12, not 6. However, the `x` in my base workspace is never changed, which is exactly the expected behaviour.

If I want `x` to be changed, I have to set it explicitly as output to the function *and* deliberately call the function in such a way as to overwrite my variable `x`, e.g `[x y] = myfunc(2);`

As suggested in the comments, you could use `randperm` instead if you're taking every number, but a more generic example using `randsample` to take a random pick of 10 from 20:

```
% sampling without replacement is default
rand_nums = randsample(block1, 10); 
rand_ind = randperm(20,10); % 10 numbers from 1:20

for n = 1:10

    rand_num = rand_nums(n);
    rand_row = pick_matrix(rand_ind(n),:);
    % whatever you need to do with these things goes here

end
```